# node.js uploading output of imagemagick to AWS S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, imagemagick, node-imagemagick

I am having a problem manipulating the image with imagemagick then upload it to S3. The resulting object has a different (bigger) size and seems to be corrupt. If I make an intermediate step and save the output to local tmp file first and read it back, then upload the result everything seems fine. This the code that does NOT work.

```
im.resize({
    srcData: imageObject.Body,
    width: variant.width,
    height: variant.height,
    customArgs: ['-auto-orient']
}, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) {
        // This resize completed successfully
        log.err('Failed calling imageMagick, bail out', err);
        callback(err);
        return;
    }

    var fileName = cfg.aws.s3.uploadDir +
                    photo.imageId + '/' +
                    variant.width + 'x' + variant.height + '.jpg';
    log.info('Storing image at S3 ' + fileName);
    //fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/xxx.jpg', stdout, 'binary');
    //stdout = fs.readFileSync('/tmp/xxx.jpg');
    var x = new Buffer(stdout);
    console.log(x);
    s3.putObject(
        {
            Bucket: cfg.aws.s3.bucket,
            Key: fileName,
            Body: x,
            ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
            ACL: 'public-read'
        },
        function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                // Failed saving to S3
                log.error('Failed saving to S3', err);
            }

            callback(err);
        }
    );
});
```

Uncomment the fileWriteSync and fileReadSync and it works properly.

The output of the console.log(x) command in two cases:
BAD:

> Buffer c3 bf c3 98 c3 bf c3 a0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 01 00
>   01 00 00 c3 bf c3 9b 00 43 00 06 04 05 06 05 04 06 06 05 06 07 07 06
>   08 0a 10 0a 0a 09 09 ...>

GOOD:

> Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff
>   db 00 43 00 06 04 05 06 05 04 06 06 05 06 07 07 06 08 0a 10 0a 0a 09
>   09 0a 14 0e 0f 0c 10 ...>

as you can see good one is a proper jpeg, the bad one though contains similar sequences like 4a 46 49 46 = JFIF, however some bytes are off, and there are shifts, the whole file is bigger by about 20% in the bad case.

Something to do with encoding? I've tried several things but I am lost at this point.

Thanks!

***Update #1:***
Apparently it is related to UTF encoding but I still don't completely understand what happens in this case. Apparently c3 bf c3 98 c3 bf c3 a0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 is UTF encoding of:

```
U+00FF LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS character (&#x00FF;)
U+00D8 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH STROKE character (&#x00D8;)
U+00FF LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS character (&#x00FF;)
U+00E0 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE character (&#x00E0;)
U+0000 <control> character
U+0010 <control> character
U+004A LATIN CAPITAL LETTER J character
U+0046 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F character
U+0049 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I character
U+0046 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F character
U+0000 <control> character
U+0001 <control> character
```

when FF D8 FF .. is exactly what I was expecting.

I know how to make the code work without temporary files (replace var **x = new Buffer(stdout);** with var **x = new Buffer(stdout, 'binary')** )

However I still can't say I completely understand what happened here, this should without the Buffer() wrapping, which component has the problem? imagemagick? Buffer?

Comment: Woah, this is a weird issue. Well worded question and interesting problem. I'll see if I can look into this sometime today : )

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you do not put the stdout into a new buffer object? does it come out of node-imagemagick as a string? If it comes out as a buffer anyway, the corruption could be the double buffer wrapper...

Comment: Did you try ` Body: stdout`, in your putObject options to just send stdout without wrapping in an unnecessary buffer?

Comment: yes indeed, my original code did not have the Buffer wrapping, the result was the same. The reason I added the wrapping was when I tried to do console.log(stdout) I just got a binary dump of a complete buffer on my screen, with the buffer I get this nice printout, but again it makes no difference on the blob in S3. In any case see the c3 bf c3 header in the bad case? its repeating. And, surprise http://forums.adobe.com/thread/598204 this is something standard. I wonder what is it, clearly fs.writeFile handled it properly

Comment: You ever find the answer to this I am looking for a similar solution of taking a im.resize method and outputting it straight to S3

Comment: Just a guess but maybe because stdout is initialized not as buffer but as string ? https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick/blob/master/imagemagick.js#L42

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously massively late however I just came across this question myself, here's how I got this working;

```
ImageMagick.resize(params, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    // Handle errors

    // Save the output of imagemagick to S3
    S3.putObject({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: fileName,
        Body:  new Buffer(stdout, "binary")
    }).promise().then(function(data){
      // Success
    }).catch(function(err){
      // Error
    });
});
```

The key part to this is obviously the; `new Buffer(stdout, "binary")`. If you don't know if the response will be a buffer or not you could use the `Buffer.isBuffer` method and do the following;

`var body = ( Buffer.isBuffer(stdout) ? stdout : new Buffer(stdout, "binary") );`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the OP solved the problem, but I too had a similar problem where the images uploaded to S3 were bigger than the original files. Could you tell me what stdout contains (i.e., is it a raw byte stream?)

I solved the problem by setting my Body: parameter to use a base64 encoded buffer instead of the binary buffer. I'm not entirely sure why this solved the problem but I suspect it has something to do with this:

> Base64 encoding schemes are commonly used when there is a need to encode binary data that needs to be stored and transferred over media that are designed to deal with textual data. This is to ensure that the data remain intact without modification during transport.

source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding)

Comment: Anyway you can show your solution, I am dealing with the same issue currently.